# Count reoccurring Per Month

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to Count. Not sure if I can use the count function or utilize a case statement.

I want to count an ID but count that ID per each month if the EndDate_YYYYMM >= StartDate_YYYYMM

For Example:

```
ID    StartDate_YYYYMM    EndDate_YYYYMM
1       201601              201606
```

Desired Results: "Engaged"

```
 StartDate_YYYYMM       Count 
   201601                 1
   201602                 1 
   201603                 1
   201604                 1
   201605                 1
   201606                 1 
   201607
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't quite as straightforward as you're probably expecting. This is mostly due to a few issues with your question, which are:

- Your table structure is unknown (next time add some DDL).
- We have to assume that your dates are stored as `VARCHAR` due to the YYYYMM format.
- Producing a sequence of dates is easiest achieved with a "Dates" table, we have to assume that you do not have one.

That being said, the following query will produce the results that you are aiming for, given my understanding is correct:

```
;
WITH    CTE_DateTable
          AS (
              SELECT    #t.ID,
                        CAST(#t.StartDate_YYYYMM + '01' AS DATE) AS StartDate,
                        CAST(#t.EndDate_YYYYMM + '01' AS DATE) AS EndDate
              FROM      #t
             ),
        CTE_MinMaxDates
          AS (
              SELECT    MIN(CTE_DateTable.StartDate) AS MinDate,
                        MAX(CTE_DateTable.EndDate) AS MaxDate,
                        DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(CTE_DateTable.StartDate), MAX(CTE_DateTable.EndDate)) AS Difference
              FROM      CTE_DateTable
             ),
        CTE_Nums
          AS (
              SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ob.object_id) AS Num
              FROM      sys.all_objects AS ob
             ),
        CTE_Months
          AS (
              SELECT    DATEADD(MONTH, n.Num - 1, d.MinDate) AS MonthStart
              FROM      CTE_MinMaxDates d
              CROSS JOIN CTE_Nums n
              WHERE     DATEADD(MONTH, n.Num - 1, d.MinDate) <= d.MaxDate
             )
    SELECT  CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, m.MonthStart) AS VARCHAR) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), m.MonthStart, 112), 5, 2) AS StartDate_YYYYMM,
            COUNT(DISTINCT d.ID) AS Count
    FROM    CTE_DateTable AS d
    INNER JOIN CTE_Months AS m ON m.MonthStart BETWEEN d.StartDate AND d.EndDate
    GROUP BY m.MonthStart;
```

[Working example](https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/a537a822e12e656185e8d542584acb62)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly,then the script you are looking for is:

```
SELECT  tab.StartDate_YYYYMM
      , COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM    YourTable tab
WHERE   EndDate_YYYYMM >= StartDate_YYYYMM
GROUP BY tab.id
      , tab.StartDate_YYYYMM
```